# SQL SERVER XML BCP

Tags: sql-server, xml

I just need to create a file containing XML that is selected from a single database column.

- **This works in SSMS**  select  outputfield from xmltab -- Select the returned XML in the grid do Save-As output..xml  This  produces a nicely formatted file with appropriate line endings.  Looking at the file in a browser formats the XML appropriately, etc.
- **This Does not Work** `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT [outputfield] FROM [coTemp].[dbo].[xmltab]  FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64" queryout \\prdfiles\files\Test\ProvidersFromBCP_T.xml -c -T'`

(It creates a document that does not have proper formatting - Line endings appear to be wrong, and the file is not readable in a browser.

I have tried various switches on BCP like choosing different line endings, etc. and various modes on the FOR XML  clause of the query- like removing the binary base 64 but with similar results.

Is this because the SSMS grid presentation of the does some auto-formatting?  Maybe I HAVE to create a format file?

I was trying to keep it simple since it is a very occasional need to do the extract, but SSMS seems to run out of memory.

Any ideas on how to make it work are greatly appreciated!

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should look into using SQL Server Integration Services to produce your XML output.  There are a number of answers around here that mention how to do it if you get stuck.